# Logging exceptions from windows service

Tags: c#, .net, exception, logging, windows-services

I've implemented a windows service in C#. 
What is the best way to register the information regarding exceptions that occurs in windows service? Using EventLoger class is a good idea? Or should I implements my own logger and write exception information to some text file.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you should have an option to log more than just the exceptions, and have a way to chagne logging detail level externally. (flag in config file?). were you write log data -file, windows application log-, is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  The two fundamental questions are: why are you logging the exception, and who will be reviewing the exceptions?

Depending upon the answer to those questions, you might not want to log exceptions at all, or you might want to send an email/sms message to someone to fix things pronto.

Comment: I've developed a simple windows service for my web application that periodically removes temporary files from configured folder. Before removing the file, I always check if it exists but some exception could occur in this process. I want to log that. Not logging the exception it might be not a good ideia.

Comment: @aumanets: To me, that sounds like just the kind of thing you DON'T want to hear about or log.  It's seems like good house cleaning, but non-critical (no harm from occassional or even frequent failure). You log exceptions that you want to fix (or at least priortize for fixing). For instance an IOException would  indicate the file was still open and not ready to be deleted. As long as the file eventually gets deleted you probably don't really care how many attempts it takes. It might indicate some oher bug ht needs to be fixed, but isn't in itself important.

Answer (score 5):

Either use an exception logging/handling library like [NBug](http://www.nbusy.com/projects/nbug), or a general purpose logging library like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) (you'll need to create custom exception filters with NLog, if you use it).

If you do not want an additional .dll dependency, you're better of using internal `System.Diagnostics.Trace` & `System.Diagnostics.Debug` classes.